# If i search our web service on google, It seems that Google only brings meta data which is Korean. How can I apply meta data by language

Tags: javascript, python, flask, meta-tags

I’m developing web service using python/flask.
My web service is consisted of 3 languages, which are English,Thai and Korean.
By analyzing client ip of connecting time, we are rendering templates and static files that are made of relevant region.
I confirmed that if someone access our service bypassing proxy ip, it shows the page corresponding region.
However, If i search our web service on google, It seems that Google only brings meta data which is Korean.
How can I apply meta data by language.

Comment: You can only have one language per URL at a time. If you show Google your page in Korean, Google can only index the Korean version of it. Google can't index multiple languages if they all share the same URL. Use different URLs for different languages.

Comment: [Here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en)'s Google's guide on this issue. But yeah, you can't tell Google about language variants if you can't tell it by URL. Don't localise by IP; if you want, _redirect_ by IP, but have distinct URL for all distinct pages.